# A VM on VMware goes back on time on reboot

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, mount, vmware-tools

This is strange, I had cloned a base build VM and had it running for 3 days, starting from October 6th. Due to a maintenance issue, had to reboot the server and found it had everything lost. No configurations, no installed files and no trace of history at all.

The VM is running CEntOS 6.5.

Here is what I see in /var/log/messages - Oct 6, Oct 7, Oct 8 had no messages

```
Feb  6 17:14:50 cpt-vrt-051 kernel: Kernel logging (proc) stopped.
Feb  6 17:14:50 cpt-vrt-051 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.10" x-pid="1554" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on signal 15.
Oct  9 14:35:32 cpt-vrt-051 kernel: imklog 5.8.10, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
Oct  9 14:35:32 cpt-vrt-051 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.10" x-pid="1417" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Oct  9 14:35:32 cpt-vrt-051 kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
Oct  9 14:35:32 cpt-vrt-051 kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
Oct  9 14:35:32 cpt-vrt-051 kernel: Linux version 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@c6b10.bsys.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Fri Jan 3 21:39:27 UTC 2014
Oct  9 14:35:32 cpt-vrt-051 kernel: Command line: ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_cptvrt051-lv_root rd_NO_LUKS LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_LVM_LV=vg_cptvrt051/lv_root rd_NO_MD rd_LVM_LV=vg_cptvrt051/lv_swap SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=128M  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet
Oct  9 14:35:32 cpt-vrt-051 kernel: KERNEL supported cpus:
Oct  9 14:35:32 cpt-vrt-051 kernel:  Intel GenuineIntel
Oct  9 14:35:32 cpt-vrt-051 kernel:  AMD AuthenticAMD
Oct  9 14:35:32 cpt-vrt-051 kernel:  Centaur CentaurHauls
Oct  9 14:35:32 cpt-vrt-051 kernel: Disabled fast string operations
```

It is possible I might have done something stupid on the VMware that does a system restore. A part of .bash_history of root user reads:

```
shutdown -h now
yum -y update
mount
ls /media/
mount /dev/sr0 /media/
cp /media/VMwareTools-9.4.0-1280544.tar.gz .
umount /mnt/
umount /media/
tar xaf VMwareTools-9.4.0-1280544.tar.gz
cd vmware-tools-distrib/
./installer/
./vmware-install.pl
cd
rm -rf VMwareTools-9.4.0-1280544.tar.gz vmware-tools-distrib/
chkconfig sshd on
service sshd start
```

I am sure I haven't run these commands here. Please let me know what might have caused this weirdo? Is there anything on VMWare that I have chosen by mistake? How can I trace back the events that caused this?

Comment: You did a restore instead of a reboot.

Comment: @mailq I am using VMWare vSphere Client 5.1, I don't see a restore option.

Comment: Using non-persistent disks?

Comment: @NathanC thanks for pointing it out, that should be the problem.